# Getting field type in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I've got back into Python after a long break. I'm creating a simple data validation script at the moment. I am just trying to return the field type of a field input by the user. I'm using arcpy.AddMessage to validate my steps as I go along. I've tried googling and looking at multiple questions on here and have found nothing that works. Here is my code:

```
    #VARIABLES
gulyShp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)
#GULLY SHAPEFILE
sDep = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)


arcpy.AddMessage(sDep)


sDTy = arcpy.Field(sDep.Type)
arcpy.AddMessage(sDTy)
```

All I want is the type of the field sDep is assigned to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [ListFields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm) to list [field objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm) which has properties like type and name:

```
sDTy = [f.type for f in arcpy.ListFields(gulyShp) if f.name == sDep][0]
```

gulyShp need to be a complete path and filename, or only the filename and arcpy.env.workspace set to the shapefile folder.

I am using Listfield with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The `[0]` is to fetch first (and in this case only) item in the list.